# Very odd UIImagePickerController behavior (Pic attached)

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I've been totally unable to get the bottom of this. I am capturing a camera image. My preview image looks like the image below?

The resulting captured image is actually just fine. It's just that the preview appears like the image below?

That's my image there in the middle..... all TINY... ?

Screenshot of issue:

[image: http://i445.photobucket.com/albums/qq172/kilobytedump/photo-2.png]

Anyone have any idea?

The code I am using:

```
//Open the Camera view
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.delegate = self;
picker.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sure! There's nothing unusual and I've used the camera in many other apps. That's what's confusing me. Code:
//Open the Camera view
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.delegate = self;
picker.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];

Comment: Yip. Sorry about the formatting of that last reply (iPhone)

Comment: I've.. allowsEditing = NO, cleaned etc, rebooted..? Standard code used elsewhere in other apps. Really stumped.

Comment: Update: I had to leave it in the end. Couldn't get to the bottom of it at all. I've used the EXACT same code since in other apps just fine.